# Spring Java model property limit of 1,000?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using Spring/Hibernate and this is the first time I have a Java model object with about 1500 properties (I work at a research center and there is a data collection form that is just this long) and I'm getting the following error during application startup:

```
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.27
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC driver: MySQL Connector Java, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.27 ( Revision: alexander.soklakov@oracle.com-20131021093118-gtm1bh1vb450xipt )
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: on_close
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
INFO 12/11 18:43:16 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
ERROR 12/11 18:43:18 edu.ucsf.lava.core.dao.hibernate.LavaDaoHibernateImpl - Unable to load bean 'lavaDao' from application contextorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lavaDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/core/core-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/local/pedi/pedi-env-tomcat6.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/core/core-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
```

I know that MySQL InnoDB tables have a 1000 column limit, so I split the model object into two tables, with table 1 having about 960 columns and table 2 having the rest. It appears to be a problem with the number of properties because when I reduce the properties down to below 1000 the application starts up fine, but when I add more properties I get the above error. Since hibernate doesn't have a specific limit on number of properties, could the problem be with JDBC? Is there a JDBC property that I can set to allow for large number of columns? Is the problem elsewhere? I've also tinkered around with MySQL my.cnf settings to no avail.

Thanks for any advice/help.

Comment: Just curious why do you need one table with 1500 columns? What is big enough of an entity that requires all that data in one row instead of in multiple tables?

Comment: I think it is some problem with the configuration. first check if the config is all good.

Comment: Obviously the problem is you can't create the bean 'sessionFactory'. You should just debug in net.sf.cglib.core to see why it fails.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. You don't have a problem during compilation but at startup of your application!

Comment: One way to test is to create a light weight object of that particular entity i.e., add only 2 properties and map only those two, get rid of the entity which has about 1500 properties. try to restart the server. If you get the same error, then something is wrong with your config as the sessionfactory is not created.

Comment: t0mppa, I'm porting over an already published research data collection form with 1500 variables. Insane I know. Deinum, I put more of the stack trace. baba, debuggin at net.sf.cglib.core doesn't give me much information since by that point the error message is null. This is driving me nuts! Fewer properties and it works, more, I get this error.

Comment: If there is such a limit, the same limit can apply to sql queries results. Check that the sql generated underneath doesn't join two wide tables but issues two separate queries to populate the object(s) properties.

Comment: Oops haven't seen the date! :-)